# Panda3Dのカメラ変換について

Tags: python

```
class click(DirectObject):
    def __init__(self):
        self.accept('space',self.reset)

    def reset(self):
        base.camera.setPos(0,0,0)
        base.camera.lookAt(0,0,0)
```

省略してありますが、上記のようなコードで
スペースを押したら、一瞬だけその位置には戻るが
すぐに元の視点に戻ってしまうのですが、どうすれば戻した視点を維持できるのでしょうか？

教えてください。お願いします。